# NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat not working in iOS 8 but working right on iOS 7.1 and below

Tags: objective-c, xcode, ios7, ios8, nslayoutconstraint

I have been going almost crazy trying to figure this out.   These codes for breadcrumbs work perfectly in iOS 7.1 and below.  It puts them at (40, 44) inside my apps.  If I modify these codes on iOS 7.1 and below, the breadcrumbs would moved and follow.

However, it does nothing to iOS 8.   The breadcrumbs were put at some odd -x, -y, that we can only see the tails of it.  I try changing the points and test them on iOS 8, and it budge not.

Maybe somebody can help me out and tell me what I did wrong.  or if it is a bug in iOS 8 with constainsWithVisualFormat?

```
[self.view addConstraints:
 [NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"H:|-40-[_myBreadCrumbControl]"
                                         options:0 metrics:nil
                                           views:@{@"_myBreadCrumbControl": self.myBreadCrumbControl}]];

[self.view addConstraints:
 [NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"V:|-44-[_myBreadCrumbControl]"
                                         options:0 metrics:nil
                                           views:@{@"_myBreadCrumbControl": self.myBreadCrumbControl}]];
```

Thanks.

Comment: mb it's related with `layoutMargins` a new property of UIView?

Comment: Bimawa,  care to explain more in details?   How does layoutMargins effecting current code?

Comment: can you share app with your issue?

Comment: Unfortunately, I can't share the code.  I tried to go into Debug View Hierarchy, and it produces nothing.    Debug View Hierarchy works when I move to open document in different view controller.  But nothing during overall view.

Comment: Ok, I dig deeper using Debug View Hierarchy and found that the Bread Crumb Control View is exactly where I needed it to be.  However it is the Bread Crumb Views (UIButtons attached to the control that's going haywire).  It looks like the constraints that was working for iOS 7 is not being applied in 8

Comment: Strange behavior, can you create simple project and reproduce this issue? In my project i found two nuance related with ios8:

1. [self.view layoutSubview] not call sometimes:\
2. UIButton hasn't width and height anymore... (And now i need setup constraints for size)

but with your trouble i need code with issue for debuging and experement with it.

Comment: Bimawa,  Thank you for your help.  I have resolved my bugs yesterday.     As stated earlier, the BreadCrumbViews were not attached to the BreadCrumbControl.   I created constraint to link the first BCV to the BCC, and all is working well.  I don't know why it is working in iOS 7.1 regardless of the change

Comment: ou strange realy. So ok.! And GL :)